# How to access all functions of all nested objects within an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, faker

I'm importing the [faker][1] library & creating a `method` to return all [faker][1]'s `methods` like so:

```js
const faker = require('faker')

const getMethods = obj => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter((method) => typeof obj[method] === 'object')

console.log(getMethods(faker))
```

However, I'm just getting the first level `objects`:

```js
[
  'locales',        'locale',
  'localeFallback', 'definitions',
  'fake',           'unique',
  'mersenne',       'random',
  'helpers',        'name',
  'address',        'animal',
  'company',        'finance',
  'image',          'lorem',
  'hacker',         'internet',
  'database',       'phone',
  'date',           'time',
  'commerce',       'system',
  'git',            'vehicle',
  'music',          'datatype'
]
```

I would like to get all `methods` belonging to these `objects` instead.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker

Comment: So recurse into them...

Comment: Recursion or use `for...in`. If you need *all* including non-enumerable ones, then you need recursion + `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @VLAZ answer, I was able to figure it out using [`for ...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) like so:

```js
const faker = require('faker');

const getObjects = (obj) => {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter((method) => typeof obj[method] === 'object' || typeof obj[method] === 'function');
};

const getMethods = (object) => {
  const availableMethods = []; 
  for (const property in object) {
    availableMethods.push(...getObjects(object[property]));
  };

  return availableMethods;
};

getMethods(faker); // returns all methods in an array
```